# When did "Enable NuGet Package Restore" become available in VS2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, msbuild, nuget

I have two machines:  both run Visual Studio 2013 Professional, one with SP3 and one with SP5.  The "Enable NuGet Package Restore" option does not appear in the SP3 one and it appears that Rebuild Solution does not correctly download NuGet Packages on that one.

When exactly did this feature become available in VS 2013 and was it via service pack or some other extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I started using this feature on VS2012, so it should be there since VS2013 SP1.

take a look at this question which might have the answer you need.
[VS2012 Enable NuGet Package Restore disappears, missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15435366/vs2012-enable-nuget-package-restore-disappears-missing)